# Creating a database for my baseball simulator

Tags: java

I just finished a course in college called foundations of programming. This class was taught in Java. Just so you have an idea of my ability level, these are the things we learned about: object-oriented design, classes, interfaces, packages, inheritance, delegation, observers, MVC, exceptions, assertions.
Anyway, because I have time this summer I wanted to design a baseball simulator similar to what this writer created: http://www.hardballtimes.com/10-lessons-i-learned-from-creating-a-baseball-simulator/

In my project, I want to basically create a database of a bunch of MLB players and their statistics. What are some ways I can create a database using Java? I would also be open to learning something new that could work with my background. Also, is there a way I can automatically enter statistics from MLB.com? I do not want to manually enter a bunch of statistics.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question...not sure it applies to this forum.  Also, there are a ton java frameworks to build an application.  Spring is a very popular one; you can also use Java EE 7 to minimize dependencies: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/  The database layer is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm#BNBPY  I'd start with one of the examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-basicexamples001.htm#GIQST

There seems to be an api on mlb.com to extract stats: http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/

Comment: I agree with the scope of this question being too broad. Stack overflow is geared towards helping you solve specific issues with your code. It's not intended to tell you how to build an entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need an ORM. Check this out http://hibernate.org/orm/ . Hibernate is a nice framework to create a persistence layer for your application. I would suggest going through some tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this goal is very simple, all you need to learn is SQL. You will be able to code an applet while being connected to the database for the players you will have avaliable.

First Thing  is to learn SQL, here is a link to Oracle Docs,
[Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm), then you will need to get a copy of SQL Developer. I would recommend reading chapter 3 to chapter 9 to get a base for the SQL, because that is really all you need to know for this simple database.

Once you have completed building the database you will need to study the [java.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), the link will send you to the java docs where you will be able to study the code needed to hook the database up to your java code.

**Note:** Database does not have to be online as long as its on the same computer as the game is being built and run on.